# Can't do System Restore (failed to extract the file, 0x80070301)

Tags: windows-10, data-recovery, system-restore, windows-installer

> System Restore did not complete successfully. Your computer's system
>   and settings were not changed. Details: System restore failed to
>   extract the file (C:\Windows\Installer) from the restore point. An
>   unspecified error occurred during System Restore. (0x8007301)

Things I have tried:

- Uninstalled antivirus completely, disabled windows firewall
- ran sfc /scannow  - no errors found
- couldn't access windows restore from safe mode..
- different restore points
- restarting VSS service ( it's set on automatic)
- enabled services: Virtual Disk, Encryption service

I have used tweaking.com reset file permissions few months ago, and windows somehow things I'm using built in administrator account, so I can't launch any store apps and settings.. Could that be the problem  ?

I also added all possible permissions to Windows/Installer folder..

[image]

[image]

And I can't find anything system restore related in event viewer...

There were few errors before restore:

```
The server {9BA05972-F6A8-11CF-A442-00A0C90A8F39} did not register with DCOM within the required timeout.
The User Data Storage_b05d3 service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 1 time(s).  The following corrective action will be taken in 10000 milliseconds: Restart the service.
The Sync Host_b05d3 service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 1 time(s).  The following corrective action will be taken in 10000 milliseconds: Restart the service.
The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID {D63B10C5-BB46-4990-A94F-E40B9D520160} and APPID {9CA88EE3-ACB7-47C8-AFC4-AB702511C276} to the user NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM SID (S-1-5-18) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.
```

After:

```
The luafv service failed to start due to the following error: 
This driver has been blocked from loading
```

This is really important. I lost a database file and when I recover it through shadow copy (ShadowExplorer) it's corrupted, even when recovering from date when everything was OK and working. So I'm hoping it would recover properly that file when I do system restore..

BTW is it possible for shadow copy to compress a file who has no extension ?

The particular file was without any extension, but I didn't find 'compress' option checked in that file and parent folder (google chrome folder).

It's strange that every shadow copy version restores corrupted sqlite 3 database file.. The most oldest shadow copy I have is from Nov. 25th, and then everything was OK, but when I'm recovering it now - it's corrupted. I also checked it with Recuva and it showed that there were no overwritten clusters or anything like that.

[image]

Comment: 0x80070301 = ERROR_COMPRESSION_DISABLED ( Compression is disabled for this volume). go to the drive options and allow compression/indexing

Comment: Last time I enabled compression on C: drive all my mp3 files were corrupted... I'm gonna try..

Comment: backup all data first

Comment: Is there a way to enable compression for the volume, but don't compress right away ? I want to enable compression only for that particular Installer folder

Comment: I enabled NTFS compression in registry, and now restore restores nothing, it stays on restore screen for hours. I have to turn off with a button..

Comment: is the volume shadow copy service runing?

Comment: Yes, it's set on Automatic.

Comment: hm, I have no other ideas. I use a 3rd party tool to generate full imaegs of my drives and backup important data like databases to an external RAID1 drive to make sure the data are safe. I have no other idea how to fix this ugly system restore issue.

Comment: I checked event viewer and in every error I still find the same error which means that compression is disabled for this volume, even though I enabled it in registry.. I also enabled compression by using fsutil, but nothing changed.. It's always stuck on "System restore is initializing..." screen.. Some error messages: `System restore ended unexpectedly because of power loss or a program error. Additional information: (Windows Update).` `System restore ended unexpectedly because of power loss or a program error. Additional information: (DestroyWindowsSpying).`

Comment: Finally I restored... It took 3 hours and 20 minutes... Everywhere I looked, people said it shouldn't take longer than 15-20 minutes, but in my case it was this long.. Maybe because lots of things had changed in 10 day period.. BTW my HDD size is 750 GB, free size 320 GB. And AppData folder was not restored, even though it's a program file folder, and SR should restore programs and their files...

Comment: Nice to hear this :). Post it as answer.

Comment: Just tried different restore point and the error still occurs.. (0x80070301)

Comment: so your issue is not solved? I thought it worked? Were you not ale to get your file from the restore point?

Comment: The oldest 4 restore points didn't work, but newer ones worked. The file I was trying to recover was corrupt on all shadow copies, in some versions even overwritten with other text files. I guess it's because it didn't had extension...

Comment: I have no other idea how to recover the file. Learn from it and create backup of the files or use a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control software